# PowerBI Web Embed Has Mixed Refresh Data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

My organization recently publish a PowerBI dashboard via the Publish to Web and an embed code. We have configured a daily refresh via a gateway running on a virtual machine that's always on. The data refreshes automatically daily. This is all successful and works well.

The issue we are running into is that the data seems to update incrementally on the embedded version. For example, data in one tab will update to the most current data, while changing a slicer selection will continue to display the previous day's data.

This is incredibly confusing, especially as it's a publish facing dashboard.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks!